# Drop frames to make output match input

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, rtp, gstreamer-1.0, janus-gateway

I have a gstreamer pipeline that looks like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=10101 ! capsfilter caps="application/x-rtp,clock-rate=90000,media=video,encoding-name=VP8,payload=96" ! rtpvp8depay ! avdec_vp8 ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,height=240,width=320, format=I420 ! videoconvert ! vp8enc ! rtpvp8pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=10606
```

I'm using janus to stream rtp packets to the input port.

this pipeline is really slow for me: Output video is 4-5s behind the input video. Is there an element in gstreamer that matches the output to the input even if that means we have to drop some frames? Or compensate some other way

Comment: Not sure what "slow" means in this context. Does it encode in real time? Then it is not too slow. If you actually meant "latency" I would look into `vp8enc` element configuration. If it does lookahead for example (which is quite common for off-line encoding) this can cause very high latency in a live scenario as it has to wait for a specific amount of time before it can actually encode. See the x264enc element for example which has a tune=zerolatency option for specifically these scenarios.